# Filtering a Result Set based on changed columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using the following sample code I'm trying to remove rows that have not had columns changed based on the scalar @CompareFields

```
create table #ResultSet_fields(
 claimId int,
 adjustmentVersion int,
 ServiceDateFrom date,
 ServiceDateTo date,
 ProcedureCode varchar(10),
 PlaceOfService varchar(3)
 )

declare @CompareFields varchar(max)

select @CompareFields = 'ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService'

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1010,1,'5/5/2015','5/5/2015',92213,11

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1010,2,'5/5/2015','5/5/2015',92213,11

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1010,3,'5/5/2015','5/5/2015',92214,11

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1011,1,'5/5/2015','5/5/2015',5555,11

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1012,1,'5/7/2015','5/7/2015',66666,11

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1012,2,'5/7/2015','5/7/2015',66666,13

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1013,1,'5/7/2015','5/7/2015',99999,11

insert into #ResultSet_fields (ClaimId,adjustmentVersion,ServiceDateFrom,ServiceDateTo,ProcedureCode,PlaceOfService) select 1014,1,'5/9/2015','5/9/2015',99999,11
```

I only want rows that have had a column change of 'ProcedureCode' and 'PlaceOfService' between adjustment versions.

ex. since the row with ClaimId '1010' had a 'ProcedureCode' change and row with claimId '1012' had a 'PlaceOfService' change I would only like those rows to remain in the Result Set.

I have thought about using the EXCEPT clause or UPDATE() trigger but I'm having trouble forming the syntax.

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `LAG` to get the previous row's value to compare to.**

```sql
SELECT
  ClaimId,
  adjustmentVersion,
  ServiceDateFrom,
  ServiceDateTo,
  ProcedureCode,
  PlaceOfService
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ServiceDateFrom_prev = LAG(rs.ServiceDateFrom) OVER (PARTITION BY rs.ClaimId ORDER BY rs.adjustmentVersion),
      ServiceDateTo_prev   = LAG(rs.ServiceDateTo  ) OVER (PARTITION BY rs.ClaimId ORDER BY rs.adjustmentVersion),
      ProcedureCode_prev   = LAG(rs.ProcedureCode  ) OVER (PARTITION BY rs.ClaimId ORDER BY rs.adjustmentVersion),
      PlaceOfService_prev  = LAG(rs.PlaceOfService ) OVER (PARTITION BY rs.ClaimId ORDER BY rs.adjustmentVersion)
    FROM #ResultSet_fields rs
) rs
WHERE (
    @CompareFields LIKE '%ServiceDateFrom%' AND ServiceDateFrom <> ServiceDateFrom_prev
 OR @CompareFields LIKE '%ServiceDateTo%'   AND ServiceDateTo   <> ServiceDateTo_prev
 OR @CompareFields LIKE '%ProcedureCode%'   AND ProcedureCode   <> ProcedureCode_prev
 OR @CompareFields LIKE '%PlaceOfService%'  AND ProcedureCode   <> PlaceOfService_prev
);
```

If you want to use indexes, or you have a lot of columns ot compare, you can use dynamic SQL

```sql
DECLARE @lagCols nvarchar(max), @whereFilters nvarchar(max);

SELECT
  @lagCols = STRING_AGG(CAST(
'    ' + QUOTENAME(c.name + '_chg') + ' = LAG(rs.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') OVER (PARTITION BY rs.ClaimId ORDER BY rs.adjustmentVersion)
    '      AS nvarchar(max)), ',')

 ,@whereFilters = STRING_AGG(CAST(
    QUOTENAME(c.name + '_chg') + ' <> ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
      AS nvarchar(max)), ' OR
    ')

  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CompareFields, ',') s
  JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c ON c.name = TRIM(s.value)  -- make sure to get the right database
  WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ResultSet_fields');

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT
  ClaimId,
  adjustmentVersion,
  ServiceDateFrom,
  ServiceDateTo,
  ProcedureCode,
  PlaceOfService
FROM (
    SELECT *,
' + @lagCols + '
    FROM #ResultSet_fields rs
) rs
WHERE (
    ' + @whereFilters + '
);
';

PRINT @sql; -- for testing
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: The first query was returning what I needed but I can't hardcode the column names (like you said I might have a lot of columns to check and they could change). I tried running the second query but I couldn't get it working in sql-server. It complained about being not being able to bind 'c.name' and it was looking for parenthesis by @whereFilters and STRING_SPLIT but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server: 14.0.3401.7 (X64). I was able to get the second query to work. I just had to change 't.adjustmentVersion' to 'rs.adjustmentVersion' and add the '@' to whereFilters in the where clause. Can you fix that so I can mark you answer? Thank you so much.